# Error while creating database in navicat

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql2, navicat

I am trying to create a mysql database with navicat but when i try to link to it it gives me an error in:

```
'connect': Unknown database 'hello' (Mysql2::Error)
```

([see image](http://snag.gy/WiUpO.jpg))

Or when i search for existing databases in terminal ([see image](http://snag.gy/WiUpO.jpg) ) they do not all show up. 
Not sure where i am making a mistake?

Comment: if your purpose is to create db and you don't care much about actually using navicat you may: `rake db:create` to create db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error before you most likely have more than 1 instance of MySQL running ad each of ur applications is linking/accessing a different one. 
try

```
mysqld stop
```

or

```
sudo mysqld stop
```

Then try restart both applications and you should now be able to create a database with navicat and find it using terminal